# DynamoDB - UUID and avoiding a full table scan

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

This is my use case:

I have a JSON Api with 200k objects. The dataset looks a little something like this: date, bike model, production time in min. I use Lambda to read from a JSON Api and write in DynamoDB via http request. The Lambda function runs everyday and updates DynamoDB with the most recent data.

I then retrieve the data by date since I want to calculate the average production time for each day and put it in a second table. An Alexa skill is connected to the second table and reads out the average value for each day.

First question: Since the same bike model is produced multiple times per day, using a composite primary key with date and bike model won't give me a unique key. Shall I create a UUID for the entries instead? Or is there a better solution?

Second question: For the calculation I would need to do a full table scan each time, which is very costly and advised against by many. How can I solve this problem without doing a full table scan?

Third question: Is it better to avoid DynamoDB altogether for my use case? Which AWS database is more suitable for my use case then?

Comment: How often will be doing the calculation and how often will you need to read it?

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, uuid or any other unique identifier (ex: date+bike model+created time) as pk is fine.
2. It seems your daily job for average value is some sort of data analytics job not really a transaction job. I would suggest to go with a service support data analytics such as  Amazon Redshift. You should be able to add data to such database service using Dynamodb streams. Alternatively, you can stream data into s3 and use a service like Athena to get the daily average.

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple database model that you could use for this task:

- PartitionKey: a UUID or use any combination of fields that provide uniqueness.
- SortKey: Production date, as a string, i.e. `2020-07-28`

If you then create a secondary index which uses as PK the Production date and includes the production time, you can then *query* (not scan) the secondary index for a specific date and perform any calculations you need on production time. You can then provision the required read/write capacity on the secondary index and the table independently.

Regarding your third question, I don't see any real benefit of using DynamoDB for this task. Any RDS (i.e. MySQL), Redshift or even S3+Athena can easily handle such use case. If you require real time analytics, you could even consider AWS Kinesis.

Comment: If this is really the OP's only use case, then I agree S3+Athena would probably be a better choice.